# Constraint validator old value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validator within a spring boot application.
I want to create an annotation, which will be validating updateability of a field. Something like @Updatable(WHILE_NEW).
I have created custom hibernate validator according to hibernate docs.

```
public class UpdatableConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UpdatableConstraint, Object> {
    Updatable updatableMode;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UpdatableConstraint updatableConstraint) {
        this.updatableMode = updatableConstraint.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object field, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        ...some logic...
        return result;
    }

}
```

My question is, if there is a way to find out whether the operation which is being validated is CREATE or UPDATE?
And if it is UPDATE, is there a way to find out the old value of validated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Spring Boot but I can say for sure that you won't be able to do that inside the Hibernate Validator boundaries.

Hibernate Validator just sees the current state of a bean and has absolutely no idea of its lifecycle.